# Fatal error with jigoshop and woocommerce

Tags: plugins, fatal-error, jigoshop

I am using woocommerce on my site. Is jigoshop necessary for the functionality of woocommerce?

I deleted the plugin jigoshop from the admin and then some links and pages disappeared (like the shop archive and other pages). So I tried to reinstall jigoshop and now I’m getting this:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_shop() (previously declared in /home/blaa/public_html/blaaa.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-core-functions.php:442) in /home/blaah/public_html/blaa.com/wp-content/plugins/jigoshop/jigoshop.php on line 646

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce is a fork (modified copy) of Jigoshop. You can run just one of those plugins, not both.

The error is a result of declaring the same function declared two times, because this function was not changed in Woocommerce.

The pages installed by Jigoshop were probably removed during the uninstall process. You will either find them in your trash, or they are gone completely.

Comment: What do you suggest? if i remove jigo woo want work ..king of in between a rock and hard place. do i actually need jigo for woo to work ?

Comment: Again, no, Woo is a copy, not an extension of Jigo, and you cannot run both at the same time.

Comment: I don't need jigoshop..but if i remove it woocommerce  will not have the shop archive page and some other essential pages ??

Comment: Create those pages in Woocommerce. Please read their documentation, it is all explained there.

Comment: Thanks! just deleted jigoshop and reactivated woo then want to menu and moved the pages back to menu. thanks again